# Why don't either of these function templates match the instantiations?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, enable-if

The following code fails to compile with Intel C++ 2013.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>


template <
    typename T, 
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type
>
void myfunc( T a) 
{ 
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

template <
    typename T, 
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value>::type
>
void myfunc( T a) 
{ 
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}




int main()
{
    double a;
    int b;
    myfunc(a);
    myfunc(b);

    return 0;

}
```

Here is the error output:

```
ConsoleApplication1.cpp(33): error : no instance of overloaded function "myfunc" matches the argument list
1>              argument types are: (double)
1>      myfunc(a);
1>      ^
1>  
1>ConsoleApplication1.cpp(34): error : no instance of overloaded function "myfunc" matches the argument list
1>              argument types are: (int)
1>      myfunc(b);
1>      ^
1>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `std::cout << T`? Do you mean `a`?

Comment: you cannot have a template nontype parameter of type void. tell enable_if to give you a type int and ptovide a default value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual and correct way to use `enable_if` in a function is to stick it in the return type.

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type myfunc(T a) {
    std::cout << a << " (integral)" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value>::type myfunc(T a) {
    std::cout << a << " (non-integral)" << std::endl;
}
```

---

For your variant, the correct way is:

```
template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
void myfunc(T a) {
    std::cout << a << " (integral)" << std::endl;
}
```

... the "enable_if" is a *default template argument*. And it does not work in your case because that function is not overloaded.

Comment: Thanks,  I do know it's more frequently used, but the variation I've used (or at least a correct version of it!) is also acceptable, and I want to use void functions in this case.

Comment: @JoshGreifer The omitted second argument of `enable_if` defaults to `void`. The `myfunc`s in this answer don't need to return any value, the return type is `void`.

Comment: Ok I think I understand -- so if I wanted the myfuncs to return int, I could use `std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type` ?

Comment: [More on the topic](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html).